# Getting data from excel to HTML,Javascript problem with NaN

Tags: javascript, excel

in the end of the script I try to subtract one value for the other and says that NaN what should I do? i need to get those information and subtract one with the another one.

```
enter code here

    //Add the data rows from Excel file.
    for (var i = 55; i < excelRows.length; i++) {
        //Add the data row.
        var row = table.insertRow(-1)

        //Add the data cells.
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1)
        cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].BID

        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].name

        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].CaseDate

        cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Checkin
    }

    var dvExcel = document.getElementById("dvExcel")
    dvExcel.innerHTML = ""
    dvExcel.appendChild(table)
    var lixo = excelRows[2].Checkin
    var lixo2 = excelRows[2].CaseDate

    var dif = (lixo - lixo2)
    divteste.innerHTML = `aaaa ${lixo2}`

}
```

Comment: Would you please share a sample of the excel file, and what you use to parse it?

Comment: semi-colons are your friend...please use them... Apparently you are attempting to operate on an undefined or null value or a value that does not translate to a number. Thus `NaN`... We can't tell because we have no data to see what would be coming through this code.

Answer (score 0):

For all I can see, seems like those 2 values are not Numeric values, neither can they be converted to a Number.

So first make sure those 2 values are defined and can be converted to a Number.

For Example, If those are date strings, you have to convert them to a Date object, and then to a Number:

```
lixo  = new Date(lixo)
lixo2  = new Date(lixo2)
var diff = lixo - lixo2
```

Please note, diff will be the difference in Milisocnds between those 2 dates, if you want the difference in another format, you will need to calculate it, (or use a helper library like `moment.js`).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Actually the 2 numbers that i have on excel file in a CELL is like 12-08-2019  and the other cell like  15-08-2019 i can get those and put in the variable LIXO but when i try to subtract say this is not a number and I would like to subtract one date from the other one. I tryed to put all the code here but the forum did not allow me

Comment: How can i convert to date object and then to number?

Comment: I tried to do this but did not work:        I dont know how to put the code here and appear with the correct format                                                                                        var lixo = excelRows[4].CaseDate
        var lixo2 = excelRows[4].Checkin
        lixo3 = new Date(lixo)
        var lixoc = Math.ceil(lixo / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) 
        lixo4 = new Date(lixo2)
        var lixo2c = Math.ceil(lixo2 / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) 

        var dif = lixoc - lixoc2
        divteste.innerHTML = `SPRR É:  ${dif}`

Comment: If I try this still says that this is not a number:                                                                                   var lixo = excelRows[4].CaseDate
        var lixo2 = excelRows[4].Checkin
        lixo3 = new Date(lixo)
        var lixoc = Number(Math.ceil(lixo / (1000 * 3600 * 24)))
        lixo4 = new Date(lixo2)
        var lixo2c = Number(Math.ceil(lixo2 / (1000 * 3600 * 24)))

        var dif = lixo3 - lixo4
        divteste.innerHTML = `SPRR É:  ${dif}`

Comment: if i use normal number on the excel cells like  1000 or 2323 etc.. it works.. but when it is a date and on excel is 10-05-2019 that NaN happens

Comment: Help me please , I really need that and I dont know where to find this answer. 1 week now doing researchs..,

Comment: What is the Library that you use to convert `excel` to `javaScript`?

Comment: how can i see that? I dont know you mean:  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/jszip.js"></script>

Comment: I would gladly help you, but I am missing some information

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here        
    var dvExcel = document.getElementById("dvExcel")
    dvExcel.innerHTML = ""
    dvExcel.appendChild(table)

    var lixo = excelRows[1].CaseDate
    var lixo2 = excelRows[1].Checkin

    lixo = new Date(lixo)
    //var lixoc = Math.round(lixo / (1000 * 3600 * 24))

    lixo2 = new Date(lixo2)
    //var lixo2c = Math.round(lixo2 / (1000 * 3600 * 24))

    var dif = lixo - lixo2

    divteste.innerHTML = `SPRR É:  ${lixo}`
```

Tried this but it is still saying that is not a number

Comment: Now is giving me a number:    -315532800000 but still not a date. and the date is coming like  Sat Dec 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0000